# Add to or replcate existing crosstab pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following data I can use pd.crosstab to create a crosstab of each obs with a colun for each possible category

```
Obs Category
1   apple
1   orange
1   lemon
2   apple
2   watermelon
2   orane
3   apple
3   apple
3   banana
```

Running pd.crosstab on this creates:

```
Obs apple   orange  lemon   watermelon  orange  banana
1   1   1   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   1   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Let's after the fact I recieve a new set of data.  How can either create a new crosstab or add to an existing one guarenteeing the same set and order of columns?

```
Obs Category
9   orange
```

Would create:

```
Obs apple   orange  lemon   watermelon  orane   banana
9   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Didn't you just change the order of columns by adding orange in the middle?

Comment: looks like I have orange twice! Whoops, but you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.crosstab(df.Obs,df.Category).reset_index()
b=pd.crosstab(df1.Obs,df1.Category).reset_index()
a.append(b).fillna(0)


    Obs  apple  banana  lemon  orane  orange  watermelon
0    1    1.0     0.0    1.0    0.0       1         0.0
1    2    1.0     0.0    0.0    1.0       0         1.0
2    3    2.0     1.0    0.0    0.0       0         0.0
0    9    0.0     0.0    0.0    0.0       1         0.0
```